# cakephp 3 saves entity although request-data is null

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i am developing a REST api with cakephp 3 and i found a strange behaviour.

I changed the routes.config so `.json, .xml` requests are possible. I also loaded the `RequestHandler` component in the controllers initialize method.

My register action in UsersController()

```
public function register()
{
    $message = array('code' => '200', 'message' => 'The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $message = array('code' => '100', 'message' => 'The user has been registred');
        }
    }
    $this->set([
        'message' => $message,
        'user' => $user,
        '_serialize' => ['message', 'user']
    ]);
}
```

Model validation:

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('username', 'create');

        $validator
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
            ->add('username', [
                'length' => [
                    'rule' => ['minLength', 3],
                    'message' => 'Username need to be at least 3 characters long',
                ]
            ])
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
            ->add('password', [
                'length' => [
                    'rule' => ['minLength', 3],
                    'message' => 'Password need to be at least 3 characters long',
                ]
            ]);

        return $validator;
    }
```

**The problem:**
If i make a post request with content header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` all works fine, a new user is saved and the validation rules is taken into account. But if i make a post request with for example content header `application/json` a empty user is saved. The reason is `$this->request->data` is null. But why cakephp saves the empty user? (in the database username and password is declared as not null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Passing `null` will not trigger validation

The first argument for `newEntity()` is optional, so when passing `null`, it's like you haven't passed anything at all, resulting in a fresh, new, empty entity being created, that is not going to be validated.

That's one of the reasons why you shouldn't do what you are doing there, you should not pass request data to `newEntity()`, but use `patchEntity()` on the entity created with `newEntity()` instead, just like it's being done in the code generated by the bake shell.

```php
// ...
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
        // ...
    }
}
// ...
```

That way passing `null` will not be accepted, and cause an error instead, as the argument is required, and must be an array.

I guess the docs need to be updated to reflect that.

### Use additional application/table rules

Additionally to validating data when creating/updating entities, there are also application/table rules, which are going to be applied in any case before saving the data. Using these rules you can prevent such problematic save operations no matter how the entity was created.

Here's a very basic example that tests a field for being "empty":

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add(function ($entity, $options) {
        return !empty($entity->get('field'));
    });
    return $rules;
}
```

See also **[Bookbook > ORM > Saving Data > Applying Application Rules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#applying-application-rules)**

### Prevent `null` from being used at all

In case `null` is an expected value, ie it's valid that it happens to be null under certain circumstances, then you might even want to add proper precautions and test the data for being `null` before trying to work with it.

### Why is the record inserted though the columns say `NOT NULL`?

Well, that's fairly easy to explain, the `INSERT` query generated by the ORM will contain only the fields of the entity that are dirty (changed), and by default that are only the fields automatically updated by the `Timestamp` behavior, so that an insert of an empty entity may result in something like

```
INSERT INTO table (created, modified) VALUES ('2015-05-06 11:34:49', '2015-05-06 11:34:49')
```

Depending on your DBMS and configuration this will not yield any error, MySQL for example will set the non passed columns to their implicit default values when not running in strict mode, so you'd only receive an error in case the actual value `NULL` would be passed for a specific `NOT NULL` column.

Comment: first of all, thank you for the great explanation. I found my code snippet on http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html#the-simple-setup (request->data in newEntity()). Your code works if i request data is not null, but if request data is null, cakephp throws a error because patchEnitiy's second parameter is null. By the way the correct method should be $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

Comment: @q0re Sorry, my bad, forgot the `$user`. And yes, passing null will cause an error, i've just updated my answer and mentioned the type hinting. I don't know your specific use case, ie whether `null` is an expected value, what should happen in that case, and whether this is part of your question? However it should be pretty easy to avoid problems by simply testing the `data` for being `null` before working with it.

Comment: now its not a problem anymore. But i just wonder why the framework does not handle the problem itself. And checking if the requested data is null on every post request is not best practice (especially the framework could do this itself).

Comment: @q0re Well, technically the value being `null` is totally valid. Depending on from where exactly it was set to `null` however might be a bug or considered problematic at least, so you might want to figure out where this happens and [**report it as a possible bug**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) over at GitHub.

Comment: That is what the buildRules() method is for. Validation is mainly for request data

Comment: @JoséLorenzo Right, forgot to mention that... answer updated.